# How can i put the buttons on the inside grid?

Tags: python, kivy

While trying to make a calculator like app i run into a problem my buttons didnt go to the correct grid
how can i fix that? Like is there a way to put the buttons in the inside grid or do i have to do smth else?I am quite new so i dont really know how to do this i tried putting self.inside.first when making the button for example but to no avail.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 3

        self.first = Button(text="1", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.first.bind(on_press= self.prf)
        self.add_widget(self.first)
        self.second = Button(text="2", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.second.bind(on_press= self.prs)
        self.add_widget(self.second)
        self.third = Button(text="3", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.third.bind(on_press= self.prt)
        self.add_widget(self.third)

        self.fourth = Button(text="4", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.fourth.bind(on_press= self.prfo)
        self.add_widget(self.fourth)
        self.fifth = Button(text="5", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.fifth.bind(on_press= self.prfi)
        self.add_widget(self.fifth)
        self.sixth = Button(text="6", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.sixth.bind(on_press= self.prsi)
        self.add_widget(self.sixth)

        self.seventh = Button(text="7", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.seventh.bind(on_press= self.prse)
        self.add_widget(self.seventh)
        self.eighth = Button(text="8", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.eighth.bind(on_press= self.pre)
        self.add_widget(self.eighth)
        self.ninth = Button(text="9", font_size=40, size=(50, 50))
        self.ninth.bind(on_press= self.prn)
        self.add_widget(self.ninth)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

    def prf(self, instance):
        print("1")

    def prs(self, instance):
        print("2")

    def prt(self, instance):
        print("3")

    def prfo(self, instance):
        print("4")

    def prfi(self, instance):
        print("5")

    def prsi(self, instance):
        print("6")

    def prse(self, instance):
        print("7")

    def pre(self, instance):
        print("8")

    def prn(self, instance):
        print("9")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Buttons` that you want in the `inside` `GridLayout` just change:

```
self.add_widget
```

to:

```
self.inside.add_widget
```